# how to put data in single line for 2 header tags html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, html-table

I have below html code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above data loads fine on page. 2 Headers with Month and Savings and two rows of data that i recieve from backend.

The problem occurs when i dont get any data from backend and i want to display error message on the first row. I am doing it as follows

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
      <td> No data to show because the request to load user info failed</td>
</table>
```

As you can see, i want to show error message `<td> No data to show because the request to load user info failed` on the first row. The problem is this data is getting wrapped up in the first column itself whereas i want this error message to spread across `Month` and `Savings` column.

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to add `tbody` and `tr`, and you can use the `colspan` attribute on the `td` element to "merge" the columns. For example, `colspan="2"` makes a cell span two columns.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">No data to show because the request to load user info failed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```